# Use middleware for specific verbs in Express

Tags: node.js, express

I have an express application where I handle authorization using middleware, `adminFilterMiddleware`

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next){
  if(res.locals.isAdmin){
    next();
    return;
  }
  res.status(403).send('403 Forbidden').end();
};
```

I apply the middleware for certain routes which should only be accessible by admins:

```
app.use('/only-for-admin', adminFilterMiddleware);
```

However, is there a way I can apply the middleware only on certain verbs, such as `DELETE` or `PUT`?

Comment: ```app.put app.get app.post```....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use `app.put('/:id',adminFilterMiddleware)` then this middleware will be applicable to all put requests. 
hope it helps :)