# How do I count the sum of specified sum in $total

Tags: php

e.g. if I pass `$total = 2` then it should calculate the sum of first
     two arrays.
 `sub1 + sub2`

**HERE IS MY CODE **

```
<?php 
    $num = 2;
    $array = array();
    $total = 2;

    for($x=1;$x<=$num;$x++)
    {
         $result = array('sub1'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub2'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub3'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub4'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub5'=>rand(1,100));
               $array[] = $result;
    }  

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($array);

    ?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
<?php 
    $array = array();
    $total = 2;

    $result = array('sub1'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub2'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub3'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub4'=>rand(1,100),
                    'sub5'=>rand(1,100));

    $temp_array = array_slice($result, 0, $total);   
        $sum = array_sum($temp_array);
        print_r($result);
        echo "sum of $total array is : ".$sum;
```

Output would be like :

```
Array
(
    [sub1] => 30
    [sub2] => 19
    [sub3] => 56
    [sub4] => 47
    [sub5] => 6
)
sum of 2 array is : 49
```

https://eval.in/539097

should do the trick. hope it helps :)

Comment: i'm completely new to StackOverflow. how do i accept the answer?

Comment: go below 3 votes of my answer a green tick mark will appear click it :)

Comment: yeah. I already did that for you bro. but i can't vote because of low reputation.once i earn enough reputation i will definitely come back and vote it up

Comment: the tick mark is just below up/down vote. it is unvisible but will appear when you hover over it. here is an accepted answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36083549/use-middleware-for-specific-verbs-in-express/36083756#36083756

Answer (score 0):

simply you can use for loop like this

```
$sum=0;

for($i=0;$i<$total;$i++){

$sum+=$result[$i];

}
```